# django Lists are not currently supported in HTML input

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Sorry for my english. I want create field, this field must contains list of files.

my serializer:

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    list_files = FileSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

But in UI i have this text

> List files
>
> Lists are not currently supported in HTML input.

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in HTML view input forms do not support lists. Either use JSON with nested serializers or don't use nested serializers if you need HTML Forms.